# Should I nest lists resource inside users resource for my todo list app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I'm trying to make a todo list app(very original ,I know :) ).I have a Lists resource and a Tasks resource . Each List has many Tasks.  Here is my routes.rb :

```
resources :lists do
  resources :tasks
end
root to: 'lists#index'
```

Now, I want to add user management(each user can have his own lists,signin/signout) to it.
Should I nest the lists resource inside the users resource ? In the future , I want users to be able to view other people's public todo lists . So, should I do it like this :

```
resources :users do
 resources :lists do
  resources :tasks
 end
end
root to: 'lists#index'
```

I have read somewhere about shallow nesting , but I couldn't understand it properly . Please advise me on how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

This way:

```
resources :users do
 resources :lists do
  resources :tasks
 end
end
```

Yours route will be for example:

```
/users/:user_id/lists/:list_id/tasks/:id
```

for showing task form, with helper `user_list_task_path(@user, @list, @task)`

Stacking more than one level deep is considered **bad practise**.

You call DB more times than required, routes look unfriendly to user, and it is hard to code you app.

Check out: [article](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/2/5/nesting-resources)